# How do you remove a method from a javascript type

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have a bit of javascript that runs on a 3rd party's website which requires me to temporarily add a function to the Array type, e.g.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() { alert("foo's for everyone!"); };
```

I want to be a good developer and not pollute the type systems of other people's code as much as possible so once the function is no longer needed I want to remove the function again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `delete`, which in general is good for removing all types of properties from objects:

```
delete Array.prototype.foo;
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/iyamut
MDN Documentation: [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/delete)

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.prototype.foo = undefined
```

or

```
delete Array.prototype.foo
```